# add object to panel in other class

Tags: java, swing, class, object, constructor

I have a main class, with a GUI. For special reasons, one object on that GUI needs its own class. So i made the class "Textscreen". An instance of "Textscreen" contains 2 JTextArea's. (I still need to write te specific methods for them, otherwise this special class is a bit unnecessary)

This is the simplified version of the constructor in the class "TextScreen".

panel is the panel where the GUI objects should appear on in my borderlayout.

```
public TextScreen(JPanel panel) {
        terminal1 = new JTextArea(4,20);
        terminal2 = new JTextArea(4,20);

        //some irrelevant code is removed here// 

        panel.add(terminal1);
        panel.add(terminal2);

        panel.doLayout();
    }
```

I think if i do something like this in my GUI Class

```
Textscreen text = new Textscreen(northPanel);
```

That the class Textscreen can acces my northPanel, since it's an argument of the constructor?

I used System.out.println to check if the constructor code is executed properly (no problem, no errors)... But i don't see my two JTextArea's (as a "Textscreen Object").

What's going wrong here?

Comment: hard to say, can u post the TextScreen class and the GUI ? is it inherited from JPanel ? maybe u miss the addition of those TextScreen objects to the main contentPane of the main JFrame ?

Comment: my main class extends javax.swing.JFrame

Comment: I discovered that the "TextScreen" Object appears when i resize the window? So my object is generated succesfully and placed on the panel, but i need to resize the window to see it?

Comment: What's the layout for the panel?

Comment: I use a borderlayout.... this special object should appear on the northpanel of the borderlayout.north position. (the center panel is a gridlayout)...